# Apache .htaccess - If directive to evaluate if home is the current page

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, regex

I'm just trying to set a header if the loaded page is home (`/`), however, I can't manage to do that. What I've tried:

```
#let's find var value - its echo / on the header
PassEnv REQUEST_URI
Header always set Echo %{REQUEST_URI}e

<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/$#">
   #some other rules - never hits
   Header always set Test "It works"
</If>
```

Could someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most probably the result of a conflict with mod_dir and the `DirectoryIndex`. (Or a standard internal rewrite, if you are using a front-controller pattern - although that wouldn't normally apply in this instance.)

`<If>` expressions are merged *late*, after mod_dir has already rewritten the request (in the form of an *internal subrequest*) to the directory index document, eg. `/index.html`. The `REQUEST_URI` server variable is updated to reflect the rewritten URL-path.

So, you either need to check for the directory index document:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/index\.html$#">
   #some other rules...
   Header always set Test "It works"
</If>
```

OR, check against `THE_REQUEST` server variable instead, which contains the first line of the request headers and does not change when the request is internally rewritten.

`THE_REQUEST` will contain a string of the form `GET / HTTP/1.1` when the homepage (`/`) is requested.

For example:

```
<If "%{THE_REQUEST} =~ m#^[A-Z]{3,7}\s/\s#">
   #some other rules...
   Header always set Test "It works"
</If>
```

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> PassEnv REQUEST_URI
> ```

The `PassEnv` directive is not required here. `REQUEST_URI` is already an Apache server variable and available to your script.

Comment: MrWhite many thanks for your help, the second option using the `THE_REQUEST` var worked perfect :) The problem with the first option is that I have a single entry point of index.php in my app, so `m#^/index\.php$#` is always true in any of the routes. Again, many thanks for your amazing answer and help ;)